# Formatting DataTable columns when adding data by rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, formatting

I am aware of and have used column formatting for a DataTable("dt") when adding columns, as in, e.g.:

```
dt.Columns.Add("myColName", GetType(Double))
```

or

```
DataColumn column;    
column = New DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.ColumnName = "MyColName";
dt.Columns.Add(column);
```

However, I am adding data from a double array, x(i,j), to dt, but adding by row.  How would I specify `GetType(Double)` to ensure the columns end up as Double?

```
Dim workrow As DataRow
For i = 0 To MyRows - 1
    workrow = dt.NewRow()
    For j = 0 To MyCols - 1
        workrow(j) = x(i, j)
    Next
    dt.Rows.Add(workrow)
Next
```

Comment: When you define the column (using either of your two methods), that is the way to set the Data Type of the column. All you need to do after that is make sure the values are of the correct type. The way you are adding DataRows in your third code block does not need to specify the column DataType

Comment: If you are experiencing a problem, perhaps re-word your question to include the problem you are experiencing

Comment: It worked out that you can format columns before adding data, so that's what I did (since I knew all the columns should be Double).

Comment: What is the datatype of x. If x is a Double, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by specifying column formats before data were added to the dt.

```
For j = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
  dt.Columns(j).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
Next
```

Although the array was a Double, and there would be no issues, this is nevertheless a way to format columns when data are added to dt by rows (not columns).